# Android Relative layout component allignment

Tags: android, android-layout

Plz validate the below relative layout

```
        RelativeLayout objRLActionBar=new RelativeLayout(this);
        objRLActionBar.setId(2534);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLActionBarParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,(int) (screenHeight*layoutHeights[1]));
        objRLActionBarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,objRLTitleBar.getId()); 
        objRLActionBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e4862"));

        ImageView objIVActivityIcon = new ImageView(this);
        objRLActionBar.setId(25324);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objIVActivityIconParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        objIVActivityIconParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,objRLActionBar.getId());
        objIVActivityIcon.setLayoutParams(objIVActivityIconParams);
        objIVActivityIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_def);
        objIVActivityIcon.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 0);
        objRLActionBar.addView(objIVActivityIcon);  

        ImageView objIVSeperator = new ImageView(this);
        objIVSeperator.setId(25342);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objIVSeperatorParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        objIVSeperatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,objIVActivityIcon.getId());
        objIVSeperator.setLayoutParams(objIVSeperatorParams);
        objIVSeperator.setImageResource(R.drawable.separator);
        objIVSeperator.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1f3449"));  
        objRLActionBar.addView(objIVSeperator);  

        TextView objTVPageName = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objTVPageNameParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        objTVPageNameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,objIVSeperator.getId());
        objTVPageName.setLayoutParams(objTVPageNameParams);
        objTVPageName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        objTVPageName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,18+sizeAdjust);
        objTVPageName.setText("House Details"); 
        objTVPageName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        objTVPageName.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 0);
        objRLActionBar.addView(objTVPageName);  

        objRLBody.addView(objRLActionBar,objRLActionBarParams);
```

And the output is is as shown below 
[image]

the image overlapped with text and the 'separator image' comes first! I need the components in this order objIVActivityIcon, objIVSeperator,objTVPageName. What is wrong with the above code plz help...

Comment: why don't you use XML to describe your layout?

Comment: for getting more flexibility, for code re usability, reducing number of lines, performance,better debugging more over i hate xml

Comment: There's articles on Android UI/Layout claiming that using XML is better in terms of performance. You can still get code re-usage using XML inflation and I doubt you will come up with less lines than using XML. Majority of the developers are using XML - so the code you'll produce will be tough to maintain and support from others. Still, everyone has the right to not follow common guidelines.

Comment: Editing XML also gives you WYSIWYG layout editor in Eclipse. You don't have to recompile and deploy the app to see the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objRLActionBar.setId(25324);
```

should be

```
objIVActivityIcon.setId(25324);
```